# apache DateUtils: parsing a date with multiple patterns

Tags: java, parsing, date, apache-commons

I want to parse a date that has different potential formats using `DateUtils.parseDate`. It seems to use the first parser, even if it should detect the difference between `23/10/2014` and `2014/10/23`.

It actually parses the date even if it is wrong, so that I can't even catch an exception. How can I do? Is it a bug? (commons-lang3-3.3.2)

Here is a code snippet

```
package snippet;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

public class TestDateFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        Date d = DateUtils.parseDate("23/10/2014T12:34:22", 
            new String[] {"yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                "dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss"});

        System.out.println(d);
        //returns Tue Apr 05 12:34:22 CET 29 which is wrong
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `DateUtils.parseDateStrictly`:

[DateUtils#parseDateStrictly](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#parseDateStrictly(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...))

> Parses a string representing a date by trying a variety of different
>   parsers.
>
> The parse will try each parse pattern in turn. A parse is only deemed
>   successful if it parses the whole of the input string. If no parse
>   patterns match, a ParseException is thrown.
>
> The parser parses strictly - it does not allow for dates such as
>   "February 942, 1996".

Internally, what it does is setting to `false` the `lenient` attribute of the `DateFormat` used: [DateFormat.html#setLenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean))

> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With
>   lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs
>   that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing,
>   inputs must match this object's format.

Example:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      Date d = DateUtils.parseDateStrictly("23/10/2014T12:34:22", 
          new String[] {"yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
              "dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss"});

      System.out.println(d);
  }
```

Comment: Any reasons why parseDateStrictly() doesnt parse format "MM/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss". though parseDate() works for format "MM/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss".

Comment: @b22 It does. This code works fine `System.out.println(DateUtils.parseDateStrictly("04/05/2003:10:15:16", "MM/dd/yyyy:hh:mm:ss"));`.  I think it's a matter of input data. Note that `h` means "Hour in am/pm (1-12)". If it doesn't works for you, then you can open a new question explaining your problem.

Comment: yes i understood this later, i was passing time in 24 clock format for which i should have used HH instead of hh thats why it was not working.Thanks